# How can I specify BSON type for coordinates when inserting in MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, bson

I have the following `document`, on which I want to create a `2dsphere index`, but the `coordinates field` must be an `integer BSON type` in order to do that. However the `data type` which comes from the `client` comes in as a `string` for the coordinates.

So I would like to change that to integer before inserting into the MongoDb so that I can create the index afterwards.
How can I do that?

```
user.saveSubscriber = (jSubscriberData, fCallback) => {
    var jSubscriber = {
        email: jSubscriberData.txtEmail,
        firstName: jSubscriberData.txtName,
        lastName: jSubscriberData.txtLastName,
        address: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [jSubscriberData.lng, jSubscriberData.lat]
        }
    }
    global.db.collection('subscribers').insertOne(jSubscriber, (err, jResult) => {

        if (err) {
            var jError = { "status": "error", "message": "ERROR -> saveSubscriber -> user.js -> 001" }
            return fCallback(false, jError)
        }
        var jOk = { "status": "ok", "message": "user.js ->  subscriber saved -> 000" }
        return fCallback(false, jOk)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Parse the string to float before storing by using [parseFloat()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp)

```
user.saveSubscriber = (jSubscriberData, fCallback) => {
var jSubscriber = {
    email: jSubscriberData.txtEmail,
    firstName: jSubscriberData.txtName,
    lastName: jSubscriberData.txtLastName,
    address: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [parseFloat(jSubscriberData.lng), parseFloat (jSubscriberData.lat)]
    }
}
global.db.collection('subscribers').insertOne(jSubscriber, (err, jResult) => {

    if (err) {
        var jError = { "status": "error", "message": "ERROR -> saveSubscriber -> user.js -> 001" }
        return fCallback(false, jError)
    }
    var jOk = { "status": "ok", "message": "user.js ->  subscriber saved -> 000" }
    return fCallback(false, jOk)
})
```

}

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using NodeJS. Is that then still relevant?

Comment: Yes it should work. parseFlaot() is a js method only.

Comment: how about the following validation method https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document-validation/ by setting the $type = "double" ?

Comment: Adding validation will restrict from the document to be inserted,  if validation fails. You were asking in the question client is sending string and you wanted to store it as float. The answer will do that.

Comment: Ah ok. I misunderstood the validation then. I thought that´s how you define the datatype for a particular field, before insertion. Yes it works. Thank you. I was just curious if there was a Mongo way of doing it, but apparently there is no.